# Accessing value boto3 dictionary response

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, boto

I'm having an error trying to get a value out of data returned from boto3.  I'm able to print the entire response (see below) but can't figure out what I need to do to get the NetworkInterfaceId out of response.

I'm running this in Python 2.7.5 because that's what the instances that need to run it have by default.  I'm new to python so hope I'm missing some simple, thanks for your help!

**Error**

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

**Code**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
response = ec2.describe_route_tables(
              RouteTableIds=[
                  "rtb-4a1efc23",
              ],
              Filters=[
                  {
                      'Name': 'route.destination-cidr-block',
                      'Values': [
                          "172.29.0.0/16",
                      ]
                  },
              ]
          )

#print(response)
print(response["RouteTables"][0]["Routes"]["NetworkInterfaceId"])
```

**Response**

```
 {'ResponseMetadata': {'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': 'a8e7ba60-7599-450a-a708-8d90e429d59e', 'HTTPHeaders': {'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'server': 'AmazonEC2', 'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8', 'date': 'Wed, 08 Feb 2017 11:51:47 GMT'}}, u'RouteTables': [{u'Associations': [{u'SubnetId': 'subnet-d7040aaf', u'RouteTableAssociationId': 'rtbassoc-867a94ef', u'Main': False, u'RouteTableId': 'rtb-4a1efc23'}, {u'SubnetId': 'subnet-e0fcd3aa', u'RouteTableAssociationId': 'rtbassoc-9f7a94f6', u'Main': False, u'RouteTableId': 'rtb-4a1efc23'}], u'RouteTableId': 'rtb-4a1efc23', u'VpcId': 'vpc-0d00e264', u'PropagatingVgws': [{u'GatewayId': 'vgw-fcf479cc'}], u'Tags': [{u'Value': 'pub', u'Key': 'Name'}], u'Routes': [{u'GatewayId': 'local', u'DestinationCidrBlock': '172.28.0.0/16', u'State': 'active', u'Origin': 'CreateRouteTable'}, {u'Origin': 'CreateRoute', u'DestinationCidrBlock': '172.29.0.0/16', u'InstanceId': 'i-0b84e502d9dc49443', u'NetworkInterfaceId': 'eni-08f55373', u'State': 'active', u'InstanceOwnerId': '444456106883'}, {u'Origin': 'CreateRoute', u'DestinationCidrBlock': '172.31.0.0/16', u'InstanceId': 'i-0b84e502d9dc49443', u'NetworkInterfaceId': 'eni-08f55373', u'State': 'active', u'InstanceOwnerId': '444456106883'}, {u'GatewayId': 'igw-7b03e012', u'DestinationCidrBlock': '0.0.0.0/0', u'State': 'active', u'Origin': 'CreateRoute'}, {u'GatewayId': 'vgw-fcf479cc', u'DestinationCidrBlock': '10.114.112.192/27', u'State': 'active', u'Origin': 'EnableVgwRoutePropagation'}, {u'GatewayId': 'vgw-fcf479cc', u'DestinationCidrBlock': '10.114.210.160/27', u'State': 'active', u'Origin': 'EnableVgwRoutePropagation'}, {u'GatewayId': 'vgw-fcf479cc', u'DestinationCidrBlock': '10.138.172.32/27', u'State': 'active', u'Origin': 'EnableVgwRoutePropagation'}, {u'GatewayId': 'vgw-fcf479cc', u'DestinationCidrBlock': '10.138.172.96/27', u'State': 'active', u'Origin': 'EnableVgwRoutePropagation'}, {u'GatewayId': 'vgw-fcf479cc', u'DestinationCidrBlock': '10.114.105.128/26', u'State': 'active', u'Origin': 'EnableVgwRoutePropagation'}, {u'GatewayId': 'vgw-fcf479cc', u'DestinationCidrBlock': '10.115.80.0/26', u'State': 'active', u'Origin': 'EnableVgwRoutePropagation'}, {u'GatewayId': 'vgw-fcf479cc', u'DestinationCidrBlock': '10.115.131.0/26', u'State': 'active', u'Origin': 'EnableVgwRoutePropagation'}, {u'GatewayId': 'vgw-fcf479cc', u'DestinationCidrBlock': '10.138.17.128/26', u'State': 'active', u'Origin': 'EnableVgwRoutePropagation'}, {u'GatewayId': 'vgw-fcf479cc', u'DestinationCidrBlock': '10.138.83.64/26', u'State': 'active', u'Origin': 'EnableVgwRoutePropagation'}, {u'GatewayId': 'vgw-fcf479cc', u'DestinationCidrBlock': '10.138.180.128/26', u'State': 'active', u'Origin': 'EnableVgwRoutePropagation'}, {u'GatewayId': 'vgw-fcf479cc', u'DestinationCidrBlock': '10.192.0.0/16', u'State': 'active', u'Origin': 'EnableVgwRoutePropagation'}]}]}
```

Comment: `response["RouteTables"][0]['Routes']` is a list. If you want to fetch `NetworkInterfaceId`, you should try `response["RouteTables"][0]['Routes'][0]['NetworkInterfaceId']`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_route_tables), you can find that `Routes` is a list. If you want to fetch the `NetworkInterfaceId`, you should loop through `Routes`.

```
for route in response["RouteTables"][0]['Routes']:
    if 'NetworkInterfaceId' in route:
        print route['NetworkInterfaceId']
```

Note that `NetworkInterfaceId` may or may not be present in the response. I figured that out from the response you have pasted here.